# Converting .msg to .eml using java

Tags: java, email, outlook-2010, eml

In our application, we are required to convert `.msg` files to `.eml` format in Outlook 2010. I would like to implement this using `Java` API. However, I would like clarification on the following:

1. What is the difference between the `.msg` and `.eml` format?
2. Are there any current `Java` APIs to convert the `.msg` format to `.eml` format?

Answer (score 4):

1. The Outlook .msg file format is based on [Outlook Item (.msg) File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). The .eml file format represents messages on RFC822 / MIME format. Formats are very different.
2. [JMSG](http://www.independentsoft.de/jmsg/index.html) is third party Java library with functionalities to convert .msg <-> .eml